# Bootstrap navbar partial collapse

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want my navbar to only collapse certain items.

For ex if my navbar looks like this:

```
Home|Articles                                           Register|Login
```

I only want "Register|Login" to collapse.

I got a semi-working method right now where I put "Home|Articles" outside of the collapse tag, but this method puts the "Home|Articles" items on its on "dropdown". Not sure if I'm explaining this very well but if you have any questions please ask.

Current code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="/Default.aspx" class="navbar-brand">Website </a>

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Test.aspx">Test</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="navbar-form" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSearch" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRegister" runat="server" OnClick="Register">Register</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" runat="server">Log in</asp:LinkButton></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLogout" runat="server" OnClick="Logout">Log out</asp:LinkButton></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Is there a way to change so the nabar collapses on small and below screen instead of medium and below? this would also fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EDIT: Is there a way to change so the nabar collapses on small and below >screen instead of medium and below? this would also fix my problem.

Yes, by default the break point has been defined in less/variables.less: `@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-sm-min;`. You should change it to `@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-xs-min;`

You have two option to compile your custom CSS with the new break-point.

- Use the customizer at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/,
- Or download the source code at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and compile your own version

Comment: Thank you, will try this as soon as I get the chance. Can't I just go in to the bootstrap.css and change it? seems easier than compiling a new version

Comment: It works :) I have to cheat a bit by hiding the items on the right when the screen is in sm-size but it looks fine :)